# Coloring Example

Tags: color

Why the number in the example is not blue?

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newtheorem{exmp}{{\color{blue}\bfseries Παράδειγμα}}
\begin{document}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{DejaVu Sans}
\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}
\exmp
test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You've put some extra `{ }` around your `\color` command. Remove them and it works fine :)

Comment: You're misusing `\exmp`: it *must* be called as `\begin{exmp}...\end{exmp}`.

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping `\color` in extra `{ }` restricts it to the content inside the brackets. If you want the whole thing in color you need to remove those brackets.

```
\newtheorem{exmp}{\color{blue}\bfseries Παράδειγμα}
```